# webapi core [FromQuery] dto model ignoring [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]

Tags: angular, get, asp.net-core-webapi, query-string, angular-httpclient

i have a controller endpoint with two parameters

1. sent from body
2. sent as a query string parameters with dtoModel

i using `[FromQuery]` for the second object ,becouse i cannot pass two object in the body

```
public class MyDTO
{

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), StringLength(50)]

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public int value{ get; set; }

}
```

api contoller:

```
   [HttpPost("getDetails")]
   public async Task<List<getDetailsResult>> getDetails(List<string> dbList, [FromQuery] MyDTO data) 
   {}
```

when i call the api from angular with empty string for "Details" fields it's sent to api as null, like:
http://sitename.com/api/getDetails?Details=&value=100

the `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` attribute is ignoring and it will return an error "The Details  field is Required"

angular http post call:

```
  public getDetails(
    dbList: string[],
    details: string,
    value: number
  ) {
    let result;
    let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.append("details", "");   

    params = params.append("value", 100);

    result = this.http.post("/api/getDetails", dbList, {
      params: params,
    });
    return result.toPromise().then((data: any) => {
      //console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
  }
```

i have two questions:

1. how i can allow calling the api with Required attribute if the value is empty string? there is any way to replace null value to empty string ?
2. why cannot pass an empty string in a url query string?

Comment: I would consider just posting... mixing get and post is a bit messy.  (just use one object/type that includes all the fields/values you need) Not sure params are sent correctly here as I think that 3rd argument is for httpOptions?.   As for the required part... if it's required, it can't be empty, but there is a setting in ASP.NET for convert empty strings to null (by default I believe this is true if the property is nullable):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.nulldisplaytext?view=net-8.0

Comment: another way to approach that is to define/initialize the property to "" on the backend: public string details { get; set; } = "";  If it's not sent, it'll be "".

Comment: i set `AllowEmptyStrings = true` , it's work as expected if i sent the data in body , i need any string value nut not null...`public string details { get; set; } = ""` not working and the value still null

Comment: `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]` works,  thank you ...please add it an answer to accept and i will think again about you suggest to work with one object

Answer (score 1):

> how i can allow calling the api with Required attribute if the value
> is empty string? there is any way to replace null value to empty
> string ?

Well according to your scenario and shared code snippet you have acually two options.

First of all using [custom model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-model-binder-sample) and another option is [ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.nulldisplaytext?view=net-8.0)

If you would like to use custome model validation in that scenario, you should refactor your code in following way: In this way, you would have more control on your model.

Model Validator:

```
public class EmptyStringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        

        var model = new MyDTO();



        if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Details").FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            model.Details = string.Empty;
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(EmptyStringModelBinder))]
public class MyDTO
{

    
    [StringLength(50)]

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public int value { get; set; }

}
```

Alternatively, you also could use of model annotations.

[image]

As you may know in .NET we have `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "[Null]")]` which convert the null value into empty string "" If this property is not set, null field values are displayed as empty strings (""). So you could modify your model as following:

```
public class MyDTO
{

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false, NullDisplayText = "")]
    [StringLength(50)]

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public int value { get; set; }

}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-model-binder-sample), if you would like to check more sample.